# How do I remove the bottom padding from a blockquote?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

There is a lot of bottom padding on my blockquotes. I can't get rid of it. See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xJja.jpg

My CSS settings are:

```
* {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
blockquote {
width: 640px;
margin-bottom: 1em;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

I outlined what I am trying to get rid of with a red rectangle. In this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xJja.jpg

Also I am using the pagelines wordpress theme.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Could you please post an excerpt of your HTML and CSS code reproducing the problem you have, here and for example on jsfiddle? Which elements are in your `blockquote`? `<p>paragraph</p>` have a default margin for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this to the end of your CSS:

```
blockquote p {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

If that doesn't work, right-click and view the source of your page to see the raw HTML. Then you'll know what elements are added to the `blockquote`.

Comment: IT WORKED: SOLUTION: I added what you put to the end of my CSS, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @JohnSmith Great, glad to hear it! If you're interested in learning more about CSS, [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) is a good resource.

Comment: If it worked, then the problem was in some part of your code that was not disclosed in the question.

Comment: Stay away from w3schools unless you want to get even more confused. (Some reasons: www.w3fools.com)

Comment: An edit of the question and a comment to another answer indicate that the problem is the use of WordPress whereby some padding or margin is set, in a manner that cannot be overridden using the universal selector `*` (but a rule with a more specific selector helped).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela w3schools lets you try things out interactively, something most CSS tutorial sites don't. This is perfect for a self-proclaimed newbie. w3fools lists only four problems with w3schools' coverage of CSS, so I don't think it's particularly dangerous in this case.

Comment: Thank you Jukka K. Korpela and Matthew Strawbridge. I do love the fact that I can try things out interactively on w3schools. Although, I now know to take them with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

You have a paragraph(as should be) in your blockquote? It's probably a margin from an inner element.

And it would be nice to see an actual example of the code. The code you show us here is not part of the problem from what I can tell.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie at this. Where can I find this code? This is inside of a wordpress theme. I am using the code: <blockquote> asdf... </blockquote> in the html box (where you write things and press update)